# Configuring the Date Popup on the WPF DatePicker Control

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have a date picker control that I use for a data collection application. It is using MvvM data binding. When going through a list of dates (see fig1) it will populate the date picker correctly. Whenever I hit new, the date pickers are nulled out. When I pull up the popup, it selects the month and year from the previous date that was set to. (fig 2) Is there anyway to default the pop up show the current month in the current year?

Note : I would like to keep the selected date to null on a new entry to force some validation.

[image: Fig 1]
Fig 1

[image: Fig 2]

Fig 2

The following image is to show what happens when I set the DisplayDateStart.[image: fig 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(original answer was horribly wrong, sorry about that)

Okay, lets try this again.

Have you tried setting the fallback to today's date?

```
SelectedDate="{Binding TehDate, FallbackValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}}"
```

Comment: Yea, but it restricts the user. I would just like the default be the current date to keep everything the same, not nessec. to restrict. Thank you though for the quick response.

Comment: @Redburn: How does it restrict the user?

Comment: It won't let me pick a day before the current date. I added an image toward the end of my question to illustrate.

Comment: @Redburn: I completely thought `DisplayDateStart` meant `StartDisplayDate` and thought my cursory scan of the docs confirmed this.  Setting the fallback value was my other guess.  See my edit.  BTW, this *should* work if TehDate is of type `DateTime?` (nullable).

Comment: Still no luck. I fear I might need to do some customization with the control.

Comment: @Will: Unfortunately no. I did some more research and it seems the best way is to do some formatting of the popup. I am coming back to this issue down the road and will post if I can get something to work. I just accepted your answer to be fair and since it helped pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @Redburn: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.